# Can't ping Docker host being connected to the host via VPN

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, docker, centos-7

I have two hosts: CentOS 7, which is a Docker host and OpenVPN server and Ubuntu as a client. I'm using OpenVPN to connect a client to the host, but the problem is that the VPN server doesn't send a reply back, i.e., it sends no packets back. The client is behind the NAT. I've checked the firewall on both sides - all types of traffic are allowed. What else should I check? MTU isn't the cause for sure. As a router, we're using Mikrotik.

Client's config:

```
remote <Server IP>
dev tun
rport 18999
lport 18999
proto udp
ifconfig IP1 IP2
secret /etc/openvpn/static.key 1
persist-tun
persist-key
keepalive 10 60
ping-timer-rem
verb 3
daemon
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
```

Config on server side:

```
ev tun.yasha
proto udp
local <someip>
lport 18999
rport 18999
secret /etc/openvpn/.keys/secret.key 0
ifconfig <IP2> <IP1>
user nobody # On CentOS
group nobody # On CentOS
persist-tun
persist-key
keepalive 10 60
ping-timer-rem
verb 6
daemon
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
```

Outputs while the tunnel is active:
**Client**:
ip r

```
default via 192.168.88.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.8.0.1 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.2 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.88.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.88.34 metric 600
```

ip a

```
tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.2 peer 10.8.0.1/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9b45:4bf5:f2d7:5375/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Server**:

ip r

```
default via 217.12.XXX.X dev eno1 
10.8.0.2 dev tun.yasha proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1
```

ip a (we have a lot of interfaces on the machine, so I omit them)

```
tun.yasha: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2/32 scope global tun.yasha
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4815:ef11:3756:faea/64 scope link flags 800 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99039/discussion-on-question-by-kt1m-cant-ping-docker-host-being-connected-to-the-hos).

Answer (score 0):

With your configurations, you only configured an IP address for the tunnel on the client.

As the address is a /32 point-to-point address, there might not be any route added by default. (That can be platform-specific.)

If you merely want to be able to communicate with the server via `IP1` but it does not work out of the box, adding `route IP1` should be enough.

If you for example want all traffic of the client host to be routed into the tunnel, you would want to use the option `redirect-gateway` instead.

For the latter you will want to make sure the client host uses DNS servers that can be accessible via the tunnel (see `dhcp-option DNS`). Also IP forwarding between the tunnel and the NIC needs to be enabled on the server.